# Animation for help overlay in iPhone Application

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

How could we create animations to implement help layout in iPhone applications like in the below image:

[image]

```
Desired Effect : When the hand image moves and point to an icon, ripple like effect is to be shown.
```

How could I implement this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this using Core Animation. Use `UIBezierPath` to make a circle layer and animate its radius. The open source [`ZFRippleButton`](https://github.com/zoonooz/ZFRippleButton) provides a similar effect, and will be a good starting point.